# 2010 ford taurus starting problems

Tags: ford, battery, starting, taurus

I have a 2010 Ford Taurus. It will not crank. When turned to the start position I hear the click but it does nothing. I just replaced the battery 2 weeks ago. All lights, radio, and AC work, but car will not turn over. What could be the issue? My gas is kinda low, also, but it has enough gas to go 30 miles.

Comment: Why all the caps?

Comment: no reason  i just had caplock on , do you have ananswer to my question??

Comment: Can you check the voltage of the battery using a multi-meter?

Comment: dont have 1 , but battery was purchased brad new 2 weeks ago

Comment: it did the same thing 2weeks ago and i replaced battery and it crunk right up hope they didnt sell me a bad battery

Comment: If your system isn't charging right, it could be it just doesn't have enough power to operate the vehicle.

Comment: meaning? alternator??

Comment: yes, or possibly a parasitic loss (something draining it).

Comment: Are you certain the vehicle is in Park?  It may not *quite* be in Park, or the "neutral safety switch" is broken or out of adjustment.  Try cycling the transmission selector lever a few times and then forcibly put it back into Park.  Or even try Neutral.

Comment: Sounds like a bad starter to me.